# CSS3 - Cross fading images with background-image

Tags: css, background-image, gradient, fade

Is it possible to make each separate background image of these hexagons cross-fade into another picture (Example: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/).

I'm relatively new to CSS and I feel this is out of my reach so I have come here to ask the great community at Stackoverflow for help.

http://jsfiddle.net/kGSCA/128/

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="hex" style="background-image: url(http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Turtle.jpg);">     
        <a href="#"></a>        
        <div class="corner-1"></div>
        <div class="corner-2"></div>        
    </div>

            <div class="hex" style="background-image: url(http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Turtle.jpg);">     
        <a href="#"></a>        
        <div class="corner-1"></div>
        <div class="corner-2"></div>        
    </div>
```

Thankyou!

- John

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your background image from the inline style and put it in the CSS.

```
.hex {
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   background-image: url(http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Turtle.jpg);
}
.hex:hover {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/450/300);
}
```

your html remains this way:

```
<div class="hex">       
    <a href="#"></a>        
    <div class="corner-1"></div>
    <div class="corner-2"></div>        
</div>
```

See the resulting

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGSCA/136/)

Of course, if you want different images, you will need to set an id to the elements, and assign the images accordingly